# Visual Studio Pro extensions with Express editions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins

I am curious if it is somehow possible to get an extension written for Visual Studio 2010 to work with Visual Studio 2010 Express.

My problem is that I've upgraded to 2010 Express, but my company is not ready to buy the full version yet.

There is an extension I would like to use, but unfortunately I cannot import it as it was built for the standard edition.

<strike>Is there any way to hack it in somehow?</strike>
I'm not advocating violating any EULA's, just curious if there is some way to get an extension working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to hack it in somehow?

If you want to violate the EULA, but that would be illegal. So no.

Comment: hack may have been a poor choice of words...i was just curious if there is some way to get these extensions working without any violation

Answer (score 1):

Express does not have an AddIn system.

Comment: extension, not add in

Comment: @espais: It does also not have an extension system...this functionality is reserved for the Professional edition and higher.

Comment: it most definitely has the same extension system that the Pro version has...you just need to specify that you're building your extension for the express edition

Comment: @espais: No, it doesn't. The AddIn/Extension system was ripped form the Express-Edition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions

Comment: actually there are now extensions that can be installed on Express, as of 2010.  When you build an extension (with the VS SDK), you can specify which SKUs it applies to, including each of the Express SKUs.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, I didn't try so I'm not sure if it will works.

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=323449

Comment: While the site does show good information, you should paraphrase the pertinent information, then link to the site for the source

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.